# Getting the value of a subject field on contact form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

using web3forms for a simple contact form on an HTML page. I was wondering if there was a way to when the user submits the form, instead of having it say "New Submission from Web3Forms" instead have it be the subject of the input in the form.  Submission is just coming back with the function name and not the actual value. Is that possible to do? THnaks

Here's the form block code

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="custom-form">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <form action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit" method="POST" id="form">
      <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="yourkeyhere" />
      <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="getSubjectValue()" />
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://web3forms.com/success" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;" />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="text" id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your subject..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="comments" id="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt btn btn-custom" value="Send Message">
      <div id="simple-msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried doing something like (in a script tag block)

```
function getSubjectValue () {
    const subject = document.getElementById('subject')
    const subjVal = subject.value
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `value="getSubjectValue()"` won't call the function, it just puts that text literally into the value. You need to call the function when the form is submitted.

Comment: The last two `</div>` should be *after* `</form>`

Comment: Why do you want to put the subject into a hidden input? Why not just use the `id="subject"` input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delete `<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="getSubjectValue()" />`
and script block and modify the following code:

```
<!--from-->
<input name="text" id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your subject..." required> 
<!--to -->
<input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your subject..." required>
```

This would automatically send the subject as a value without a need for an extra input field.
If you really need an extra field, then another way would be to use `onChange` on the field to change the hidden fields value but this is simpler imho.

Comment: thanks! yep that worked. I was over complicating it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getSubjectValue()` when the form is submitted. It can copy the value to the hidden input.

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", getSubjectValue);

function getSubjectValue() {
  const subject = document.getElementById('subject');
  document.getElementById("hiddenSubject").value = subject.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="custom-form">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <form action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit" method="POST" id="form">
      <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="yourkeyhere" />
      <input type="hidden" name="subject" id="hiddenSubject" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://web3forms.com/success" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;" />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="text" id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your subject..." required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="comments" id="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt btn btn-custom" value="Send Message">
      <div id="simple-msg"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```